How can I convert a timestamp in QuestDB to an int?
I want to use QuestDB as a source for prometheus metrics (using sql-exporter), reporting the last timestamp for a given table. How can I run the following query but return an int instead of a formatted timestamp?
SELECT timestamp FROM <table> ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 1
I tried various conversion functions and SQL casts to "int", but nothing was working.

Does this answer your question? Set unix timestamp (int) as TIMESTAMP COLUMN in QuestDB

You can use the extract SQL function in QuestDB: https://questdb.io/docs/reference/function/date-time/#extract. This has the ability to extract or convert your timestamp into many different components, including an "epoch", which will return the timestamp's UNIX epoch value.
You can change your query to the following to retrieve your table's latest integer epoch value:
SELECT extract (epoch from timestamp) FROM <table> ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 1
EDIT: This actually returns a long, which doesn't fully answer the question (requiring timestamp to be an int). We still need to cast the result as an int, using this query:
SELECT extract (epoch from timestamp)::int FROM <table> ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 1

@easleyfixed, you must be confusing QuestDB with something else, this runs perfectly fine SELECT extract (epoch from CAST('2200-01-01' as timestamp)) and returns 7258118400. You can try it yourself at https://demo.questdb.io/
